# Minecraft Pi - name 'block' is not defined

Tags: python, minecraft

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/minecraft/) for using Python2 to interact with Minecraft Pi. Everything is fine up until the "Blocks as Variables" section. Here is my code:

```
from mcpi import minecraft
from time import sleep

mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create();

dirt = block.DIRT.id
```

But running this code gives the error for the `dirt` line:

```
NameError: name 'block' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the raspberrypi.org example. It's missing an import. Add the following line and your code should work fine:

`from mcpi import block`